# How to schedule shutdown of a phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, data-connection, wifi-tethering, shutdown

I want to use my phone as a wireless router. Since I am on a time-based data plan, I want the phone to automatically shutdown after a specified amount of time (or at least close the data connection after a specified amount of time).
Basically, I want to prevent to exceed the data limit, and the shutdown is a plus. The phone is running gingerbread but I will probably install cyanogenmod 7.2.

Answer (score 2):

There are many 3rd-party apps available on the Market that allow you to set up actions (toggle cell data on/off, for example) at specified triggers (e.g. on a timer.)  [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateItPro.mainPackage) are great examples.

If you have a specific data limit on your plan (e.g. 3GB per billing cycle), a more advanced app like [3G Watchdog](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdogpro) would be a better choice.  It allows you to set and monitor limits on cell data usage, and disable it when the usage gets to the threshold.

Comment: I'll try AutomateIt; however 3g watchdog is not useful for time-based plans.